# Regex split without a group returned

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I need to split a string by a delimiter that is `<br>` repeated 2 or more times. I'm doing:

```
'a<br><br><br><br>b'.split(/(<br>){2,}/)
```

Unfortunately it returns the group as one of the tokens as per [String.split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) specification:

```
["a", "<br>", "b"]
```

How do I make it **NOT** return the group, to get just the tokens:

```
["a", "b"]
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make it a non capturing group by prepending `?:` to the capturing group.

```
'a<br><br><br><br>b'.split(/(?:<br>){2,}/)
```